# trying to get a list from one sub routine to another

Tags: python, list, global-variables, subroutine

I'm creating a list from data from a file and i cant use the list out side its original subroutine how can i just make it global so i can use it and change it anywhere i want ?

```
def selecting_qs():
    global main_list
    dif = difficulty.get()
    print(main_list,dif)


#main list order:
#Question ID  ,  Difficulty  ,  Topic  ,  Answer ID  ,  Picture ID  ,  Frequency 
def main_file_info():
    main_file = open("main_file.txt","r")
    main_file_info=main_file.readlines()
    for line in main_file_info:
        main_list=line.split("@")

    main_list=main_list[1:len(main_list)-1]
    main_file.close()

    return(main_list)
```

Comment: the best and safest way is to `return` it as you do (note that you can return multiple things), **assign** it to a variable (*function call*, this bit of the code you are not showing) and then pass it to the next function that wants to use it (in this cases `selecting_qs`)

Comment: How do i get the list from returning it ? just main_list=main_file_info() ?

Comment: yes. exactly. The variable gets assigned whatever the function call returns. In this case `main_list`

Comment: oh that works thank you

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself, although @Ev.Kounis should do it), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: That is my fault @Prune. I tend to write comments instead of solutions when the solution is *trivial*. I am not sure what the general guidelines are for such cases..

Comment: I'm encouraging, not complaining -- you are spot-on with the comments.  Once they accumulate into a solution, it's nice to roll them into an answer, get it accepted, and get the question into the proper bin for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

To pass variables used in functions around, you just have to **return** them, **assign** them and well.. **pass** them. On your current script, this would look as follows:

```
def selecting_qs(a_list):
    # global  <-- main_list this is not needed and can lead to problems!
    dif = difficulty.get()
    print(a_list, dif)


#main list order:
#Question ID  ,  Difficulty  ,  Topic  ,  Answer ID  ,  Picture ID  ,  Frequency 
def main_file_info():
    main_file = open("main_file.txt","r")
    main_file_info=main_file.readlines()
    for line in main_file_info:
        main_list=line.split("@")

    main_list=main_list[1:len(main_list)-1]
    main_file.close()

    return main_list  # returning the item(s) thus making them accessible from the outer scope

my_main_list = main_file_info()  # assigning the item(s) to a variable
selecting_qs(my_main_list)  # passing the item(s) to another function
```

If there are outstanding questions, please let me know.